# Scroll to the top of UITableView doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Im trying to scroll to the top in `UITableView`, its kind of working but its not scrolling to top (the beginning of the first cell). its just at the middle of the first cell.

I've tried these and its not going to the beginning of the first cell:

```
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated:true)

self.tableView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1), animated: true)

self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, -self.tableView.contentInset.top), animated: false)

self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0,  UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height ), animated: true)

self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)

self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
```

I need something to work as `scrollsToTop` its like when i press on the top of my `tableview`, it goes to the beginning of the first cell.How is it possible to do ?

Comment: Sounds like you're not offsetting the content beneath the navigation bar or something. The first and second line here will both do what you want. Can you show a screen shot and an NSLog of the tableview frame.

Comment: @Fogmeister , Alright give me awhile to do that !

Comment: Take a look at this too- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1797/_index.html

Comment: @Fogmeister, there was an issue with tableView frame in storyboard constraint. now it worked !

Comment: Ah, thought that might be the case :D